# Element not showing up in expected location (x)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, draggable

I think I am doing the same for two different elements (#tu, #chr_1) but they behave differently for some reason I cannot figure out.

I want the feedback element to be in the same location as the dragged window and the target so that I can give some feedback in-place.

Interestingly, the #chr_1 properly aligns in the drop: function, but the #tu element fails to do the same. It aligns vertically just fine, but has a large offset to the right in respect to the expected location.

Additionally, the #tu element shows up under the #chr_x element even though its z-index is much higher.

What am I missing here?

https://jsfiddle.net/2s4c7o3c/

```
                .draggable {font-size: 2em; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 30px; height: 30px; padding: 0em; float: left; margin: 0em; background-color: orange; z-index: 10; visibility: visible;}

                .droppable {font-size: 2em; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 30px; height: 30px; padding: 0em; float: left; margin: 0em; background-color: orange; z-index: 10; visibility: visible;}

                <div id="tu" class="draggable" style="visibility:hidden; z-index: 100;"> </div>
                <script>
                    var feedback = $("#tu");
                    feedback.draggable();

                document.write("<div id='chr_"+i+"' class='draggable' style='position:fixed;top:"+y+"px; left:"+x+"px;'>"+phrase.charAt(i)+"</div>");
                var src = $( "#chr_"+i );
                src.draggable();

            //...
                            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                                var ep = $(this).data("pos");
                                var fp = $(ui.draggable).data("expos");
                                if(ep == fp) {
                                    jQuery.data($(ui.draggable)[0],"placed",true);
                                    $(ui.draggable).css("top",$(this).css("top"));
                                    $(ui.draggable).css("left",$(this).css("left"));
    //Here it works (#chr_1) and the elements are in the same location afterward.
                                    feedback.css("top",$(this).css("top"));
                                    feedback.css("left",$(this).css("left"));
    //Here the feedback (#tu) doesn't occur in the expected location, 
    //but is at a few hundred px offset to the right.
                                    feedback.css("visibility","visible");
                                    feedback.css("background-color","red");
                                } else {
                                    $(ui.draggable).data("moving",true);
                                }
                              }
                            });
            //...
```

Comment: can you put it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2s4c7o3c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merely adding position:fixed to the .draggable style solved the problem.